# Why is $\, \int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \} \, dx \, \neq \,\int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \} \, dy \,$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

As far I know: **Double Integrals** of a function depend only on (i)Region of Integration and (ii)Function, and not on its **order of integration**.

In this case :
(i)Region of integration is a square (ABCD with AB=BC=CD=DA=$1$ units) where one of its vertices (A) lies on the origin and the opposite vertex is at C=($1,1$);
(ii) Function: $ f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$

Then, why is
$$\int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \} \, dx \, \neq \,\int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \} \, dy \,\,\,\,?$$
i.e.,
$$\int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \} \, dx \, =0.5 \,\, \& \,\,\int_0^1 \{ \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dx \} \, dy \,=-0.5 $$

Have I missed any concepts? Please help...

Comment: "We know..." how?

Comment: I mean it's the application of change of order of integration for double integrals;   $\\$
For eg.: "$\int_0^{\pi} \{ \int_y^{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \} dy$" can be easily calculated by changing its order of integration

Comment: @Suresh: Your first statement that double (iterated) integrals in general do not depend on order of integration is, of course, false.  What you may be referring to is the situation where you have proper Riemann integrals of a bounded and continuous function.  In that case the statement is true. Here you have an improper integral and the integrand is unbounded in the vicinity of the origin.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266784/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that the iterated integrals have opposite sign (seen simply by interchanging labels $x \iff y$.) Unless both are zero, which is not the case, they are unequal.

Your computed values are correct and are obtained easily by noticing that

$$\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{x}{(x+y)^2} \right)$$

When the integrand is nonnegative or absolutely integrable, then Tonelli's or Fubini's theorem, respectively,  guarantees that the iterated integrals are equal, i.e. the order of integration may be switched.

In this case both conditions are not met. In some cases the order of integration can be switched without meeting these requirements (by lucky cancellation) but there is no guarantee -- and this integral is a good example.

To see why Fubini's theorem does not apply, note that transforming to polar coordinates we have for $0 < \delta < 1$,

$$\begin{align}\int_{[0,1]^2} \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \right| &\geqslant \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\delta}^1 \frac{r|\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{r^3|\cos \theta + \sin \theta|^3} r \, dr\, d\theta \\ &= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{|\cos \theta + \sin \theta|^3}  \,d\theta \int_{\delta}^1 \frac{dr}{r} \\ &= - \log \delta\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{|\cos \theta + \sin \theta|^3}  \,d\theta \end{align}$$

and the RHS tends to $+\infty$ as $\delta \to 0$.

(Splitting the integral on the second line is permissible because the integrand is continuous on $[\delta,1] \times [0, \pi/2]$.)